# Checkboxes and Tabs (Code almost complete)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make tabs appear and disappear if the correct checkbox is selected.

**My code works but when I refresh the page or load the page the tabs appear for like 0.5 seconds and then dissapear.** Maybe it's the script delay but how do I remove this? I want to start webAdmin,webCSR,webClient hidden and show/hide with the checkboxes.

https://i.gyazo.com/8ff29fe1679a89fd4e215f98ba71375d.png

My HTML:

```js
  //Start web* hidden
    $('#tab-webCSR').hide();
    $('#tab-webAdmin').hide();
    $('#tab-webClient').hide();
    //Hide/Show Branch tabs
    $('#hasWebCSR').change(function() {
            if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $('#tab-webCSR').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#tab-webCSR').hide();
            }
    });
    $('#hasProfile7').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#tab-profile7').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#tab-profile7').hide();
        }
    });
    $('#hasWebAdmin').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#tab-webAdmin').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#tab-webAdmin').hide();
        }
    });
    $('#hasWebClient').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#tab-webClient').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#tab-webClient').hide();
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
                    <label>Deploy Apps:</label>
                    <div class="well">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" checked id="hasProfile7" name="hasProfile7">Profile7</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" id="hasWebCSR" name="hasWebCSR">WebCSR</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" id="hasWebAdmin" name="hasWebAdmin">WebAdmin</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" id="hasWebClient" name="hasWebClient">WebClient</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <label>GitLab Branches:</label>
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" id="tab-profile7" href="#profile7">Profile7</a> </li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" id="tab-webCSR" href="#webCSR">WebCSR</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" id="tab-webAdmin" href="#webAdmin">WebAdmin</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" id="tab-webClient" href="#webClient">WebClient</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps if you set the visiblity of the tabs as hidden for default. I added a style `display: none;` to your tabs. But then you have to initialize the visiblity once at startup.

```js
  //Start web* hidden
    $('#tab-webCSR').hide();
    $('#tab-webAdmin').hide();
    $('#tab-webClient').hide();
    //Hide/Show Branch tabs
    $('#hasWebCSR').change(function() {
            if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $('#tab-webCSR').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#tab-webCSR').hide();
            }
    });
    $('#hasProfile7').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#tab-profile7').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#tab-profile7').hide();
        }
    });
    $('#hasWebAdmin').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#tab-webAdmin').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#tab-webAdmin').hide();
        }
    });
    $('#hasWebClient').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#tab-webClient').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#tab-webClient').hide();
        }
    });
```

```html
<style>
  .nav-tabs li a {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
                    <label>Deploy Apps:</label>
                    <div class="well">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" checked id="hasProfile7" name="hasProfile7">Profile7</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" id="hasWebCSR" name="hasWebCSR">WebCSR</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" id="hasWebAdmin" name="hasWebAdmin">WebAdmin</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" id="hasWebClient" name="hasWebClient">WebClient</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <label>GitLab Branches:</label>
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" id="tab-profile7" href="#profile7">Profile7</a> </li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" id="tab-webCSR" href="#webCSR">WebCSR</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" id="tab-webAdmin" href="#webAdmin">WebAdmin</a></li>
                        <li><a data-toggle="tab" id="tab-webClient" href="#webClient">WebClient</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `style="display:none;"` to the `<ul>` tag, and in the beginning of the `JavaScript` code add the following: `$(".nav-tabs").show() ;`

Or you can simply add `style="display:none;"` to the `<li>` tags that you want to hide at the page load